# .net core adding a .net standard dll as a reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

create a .net standard dll , name it as Paas dll, and change the output path
..\Output\

add a class logger like below-

```
 public class Logger 
    {
        public void LogMessage()
        {
            Console.Write("test");
        }
    }
```

Now create another .net core console project in solution and add dll as a refrence ( not project refrence) for pass.dll and make copy local to false.

Also change output directory of console app to  ..\Output\

add below code in console app -

```
 var logger = new Logger();
  logger.LogMessage();
  Console.Read();
```

Build and run .net core app, but now application goes in break mode with below error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Paas, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

But if you perform same steps with .net framework 4.6.1 projects it works, why this different behavior with .net core exists and how to fix it?

github link for project showcasing this issue -
https://github.com/ankgupta067/DependencyInjection.git

Comment: Can you provide exact steps to reproduce (how to set up the projects, etc.)?

Comment: Do you *have* to add it as a reference like that, rather than as either a package or a project reference? I can't say I've seen any "old-style" references like that (with hint paths) in "new-style" .NET Core projects.

Comment: Should work fine. I'd say in current state problem is not reproducable (at least for me).

Comment: @Daisy You have to add a reference to a DLL instead of a project.

Comment: @john: What do you mean by "You have to"? My point is that I haven't seen that done in .NET Core style projects - I've only ever added ProjectReference or PackageReference elements, which seems to be preferred and certainly avoids the whole "hint path" annoyance. I was asking whether the OP could use one of those instead of a `Reference` element.

Comment: " I can't say I've seen any "old-style" references like that (with hint paths) in "new-style" .NET Core projects." -> To reproduce that (i.e. get Hint Path) in the .csproj you reference a DLL file instead of a project. Sigh. I was simply pointing out that it still exists.

Comment: @john: Ah, I see what you mean. That makes a lot more sense. I'd still urge the OP to use a project or package reference if at all possible, which I suspect would avoid this.

Comment: @DaisyShipton my requirement is to add dll as a reference , i want to know why this problem exists in dll as a refrence

Comment: I guess if you *have* to do it that way, you have to. (I'd still encourage you to try to move away from that over time.) Like Evk, I can't reproduce this - I've just tried doing it with Json.NET as a DLL reference, and it was fine. When you build the project, do you get the DLL in the output directory, e.g. in bin/debug/netcoreapp2.0?

Comment: @DaisyShipton i am trying to create a github project to share my code

Comment: @Evk added github project

Comment: @DaisyShipton added github project

Comment: You've got 4 projects there - it's unclear which program you're running, or why you've got both Paas and HsopPass. It would also make for a better question if you could include all the relevant details in the question itself, rather than relying on a github link. It sounds like all we *should* need for this is two project files and two source files...

Comment: Looks like the culprit is `<Private>false</Private>`. If you remove that, it gets copied to the `bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0` directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169063/discussion-between-ankush-and-daisy-shipton).

Comment: @DaisyShipton edited for better clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is setting `copy local to false.`  On .NET Core, in order to know which assemblies should get loaded, it uses what is called a `.deps.json` file that gets generated next to your output .dll.  In order to generate this .deps.json file, the .NET Core SDK inspects information about the assemblies you reference.  One of the pieces of information it uses is whether the Reference is `CopyLocal` or not.  See the [code here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/248ead6e1f06d6969aab8104d96d3526f0101b91/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/ReferenceInfo.cs#L50).  If you inspect your console app's `.deps.json` file, you'll see there is no entry for `Paas.dll` in it.

So in order to make this work, the .deps.json file will need to be written correctly.  Using the current tools, that means you will have to stop setting copy local to false.  If you want to open an issue for this scenario please log it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues). That way it can be fixed in a future release.

#### OLD ANSWER:

A difference between SDK-based (".NET Core style") .csproj projects and traditional .csproj projects is that by default SDK-based projects will append the target framework to the `<OutputPath>` property.

So when you say

> Also change output directory of console app to ..\Output\

What is really happening is that the output of the SDK-based netstandard library is going to `..\Output\netstandard2.0\Paas.dll` and the output of the SDK-based console project is going to `..\Output\netcoreapp2.0\`.  These are 2 different directories, so the runtime can't find the library.

To stop this behavior, edit both .csproj files and add:

`<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>`

inside a `<PropertyGroup>` element.

This will cause both projects to output directly to the specified `..\Output\` folder.

Comment: well i forgot to mention in question , i did that as well complete github link for project is here https://github.com/ankgupta067/DependencyInjection.git

Comment: Got it.  I've updated my answer in light of this information.